# Getting 'didn't match node selector' when running Docker Windows container in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

In my local machine I created a Windows Docker/nano server container and was able to 'push' this container into an Azure Container Registry using this command (The reason why I had to use the Windows container is because I have to use  CSOM in the ASP.NET Core and it is not possible in Linux)

```
docker push MyContainerRegistry.azurecr.io/myimage:v1
```

That Docker container IS visible inside the Azure container registry which is MyContainerRegistry

I know that in order to run it I have to create a Container Instance; however, our management team doesn't want to go with that path and wants to use AKS instead

We do have an AKS cluster created

The kubectl IS running in our Azure shell

I tried to create an AKS pod using this command

```
kubectl apply -f myyaml.yaml
```

These are contents of yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mypod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mypod
        image: MyContainerRegistry.azurecr.io/itataxsync:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: mysecret
      nodeSelector: 
          beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

The pod successfully created.

When I run 'get pods' I see a newly created pod

However, when I get into details of this pod, I see the following

> "Warning  FailedScheduling  3m (x2 over 3m)  default-scheduler  0/3
>   nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match node selector."

Does it mean that I simply can't run Docker Windows container in Azure using AKS?

Is there any way I can run Docker Windows container in Azure at all?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: are you sure that you have nodes in your cluster that match the nodeSelector label? try to run kubectl describe node and check

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I just did. The output is quite large, several pages. What exactly should I check, what data? Thank you again for your response

Comment: You can check if you have a node with that label, run `kubectl get nodes -l beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows`

Comment: @cookiedough thank you for your advice! This node is indeed missing. Do you know by any chance how to install it?

Thank you again

Comment: You can force this label onto a node like this: `export NODE=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[-1:].metadata.name}'); kubectl label nodes $NODE beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows` it's sketchy but likely it's going to work!

Comment: @cookiedough thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I got the error that 'The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet'. Is export supposed to work in the Azure Shell? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, AKS just provide the Ubuntu image for the nodes and cannot run windows node current. So you cannot run windows container in it. For windows, you just can use ACI and Web App for Container, or you can create your own Kubernetes cluster with Windows VMs.

Comment: You can try this, the export is simply assigning that value to a variable `kubectl label nodes $(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[-1:].metadata.name}') beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot yet have windows nodes on AKS, you can, however, use [AKS engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine) ([examples](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/tree/master/examples/windows)).

Bear in mind that windows support in kubernetes is a bit lacking, so you will run into issues, unfortunately.